# Transimpedance opamp specification

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to design a circuit that measures a sensor that outputs 20nA to 2mA.  I only need to read a sample per second so slow. I need to know what should I look for when I search for opamp that is stable:

EX Specifications:

**-Slew rate:** 0.5V/µs is that enough or is too much how do find the value I need

**-Gain Bandwidth:** I know that opamp Band  >> =1/2pi*RFCF (CF=Csensor+Cfeedback+Copamp)

**-Zero drift:**  Minimizes input offset voltage or I can use any

**-Current Input Bias:** AS Low as possible

**-Voltage Input Offset:**  As Low as possible

What else should I look for when I look for the opamp. (Below circuit is for simulation only, actual circuit will have more filtering and gain stages)
I am planning to use different gain depend on the sensor output: 10M-628 ohm

[image]

Comment: You'll be lucky to find a multiplexer that produces less than 10 nA leakage current. That blows things out of the water a little.

Comment: @Andy: MAX4581 Leakage is only 1nA which will have an impact on the result but not as much, otherwise I use a digital potentiometer.

Comment: That device is +/- 2nA at precisely 25 degC.

Comment: You're using a low-voltage single supply...which means the opamp's output voltage range may be limited. You might want a **rail-to-rail** opamp, and even then output voltage very near GND or very near Vcc may be unreliable

Comment: @Andy: Yes you are correct about the offset value,  but another option is a digital potentiometer which I can not find which has high gain such as 10M.